# How to write a trigger in MSSQL to insert dummy data into table once a table is created?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I am working on creating triggers to insert some dummy data into the table once the table is created. So when the table is created the trigger should be activated and insert some data into it. How to do it?.

Comment: Whatever you want to do, you  can't do it in the exact way that you are asking here. Could you please let us know your real requirement as there can be a different approach to achieve it.

Comment: Triggers aren't used that way, they are used with each operation done on the table (insert, update, delete), not the creation itself (would trigger only once!). Maybe you want a post-execution script, are you using a database development environment like visual studio SSDT?

Comment: How do you create the table ? via Management Studio or your application ?

Comment: For inserting dummy data. You can create Seed Data script (Couple of insert queries) for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a database trigger to detect when tables are created. Then, you could read the metadata about the table you created, and insert some sample data. Here's a working example that only supports a few data types (int, varchar, datetime, bit, numeric, and money), but should be enough to get you started:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trCreateTable] 
ON DATABASE -- A DB level trigger
FOR CREATE_TABLE --Event we want to capture
AS  
    DECLARE @tname NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @tname = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, ORDINAL_POSITION,
    CASE DATA_TYPE WHEN 'int' THEN '2'
        WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'text' 
        WHEN 'datetime' THEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
        WHEN 'bit' THEN '1'
        WHEN 'numeric' THEN '3.'
        WHEN 'money' THEN '4.'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS VALUE
    INTO #tmp_cols
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS isc 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tname
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE NAME = isc.COLUMN_NAME AND object_id = object_id(@tname) AND is_identity = 1)
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    SELECT @sql += 'INSERT INTO ' + @tname + ' (' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + column_name FROM #tmp_cols ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ') '
    SELECT @sql += 'VALUES (' +  STUFF((SELECT ',''' + VALUE + '''' FROM #tmp_cols ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') + ') '

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
```

To test, create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_tbl (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), non_ident INT NULL, varcharcol VARCHAR(10), 
    datetimecol DATETIME, bitcol BIT, numericcol NUMERIC(12,2), moneycol MONEY)
```

And then query from it:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp_tbl

id  non_ident   varcharcol  datetimecol  bitcol numericcol  moneycol
1   2           text        2018-07-17   1      3.00        4.00
```